# Product name update with sql

Tags: magento-1.9

How can we update a product's name with sql for 3 different store view? We have used the functions of Magento but it is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove existing value so there's no duplicated key.

I'll create a simple example function cause it's a lot easier this way.

```
public $_db = null;
public $_dbResource = null;

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $this->_dbResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
}


public function updateAttributeBySql($type = 'varchar', $entityId, $storeId, $attributeId, $value)
{
    $value = str_replace("'","''", $value);
    $tableName = 'catalog_product_entity_' . $type;
    switch ($type) {
    case 'datetime':
        // Special price from date and to date
        $this->_db->query('DELETE FROM '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." WHERE entity_id = $entityId AND store_id = $storeId AND attribute_id = $attributeId;");
        $this->_db->query('INSERT INTO '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." (entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value) VALUES (4,$attributeId,$storeId,$entityId,'$value');");
        break;
    case 'decimal':
        // Prices
        $this->_db->query('DELETE FROM '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." WHERE entity_id = $entityId AND store_id = $storeId AND attribute_id = $attributeId;");
        $this->_db->query('INSERT INTO '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." (value_id,entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value) VALUES (NULL,4,$attributeId,$storeId,$entityId,$value);");
        break;
    case 'int':
        // Status Visibility Tax Class
        $this->_db->query('DELETE FROM '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." WHERE entity_id = $entityId AND store_id = $storeId AND attribute_id = $attributeId;");
        $this->_db->query('INSERT INTO '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." (value_id,entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value) VALUES (NULL,4,$attributeId,$storeId,$entityId,$value);");
        break;
    default:
        $this->_db->query('DELETE FROM '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." WHERE `entity_id` = $entityId AND `store_id` = $storeId AND `attribute_id` = $attributeId;");
        $this->_db->query('INSERT INTO '.$this->_dbResource->getTableName($tableName)." (entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value) VALUES (4,$attributeId,$storeId,$entityId,'$value');");
        break;
    }
}
```

Then inside your module that takes care of updating you can call this function by:

```
$attributeId = /** YOUR NAME ATTRIBUTE ID, usually 71. **/
foreach($stores as $storeId) {
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $value = $product['name'];
        $entityId = $product['id'];
        $this->updateAttributeBySql('varchar', $entityId, $storeId, $attributeId, $value);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is not self-explanatory then I'll extend this answer with more details here and there.